# How would you understand meeting time availability?

Tags: meaning

If I ask someone, "what's your availability for a meeting" and this person replies:

> I am available Wed and Thurs 4pm-9pm.

Does it mean he is available to start the meeting anytime during this range including and up to 9pm?  Or does it mean the start time + meeting length are to be between 4 and 9?

How would you interpret this?

Comment: It would usually mean that he is going home at 9pm. But if you said you could start only at 8:45 he might make an exception.

Comment: I would take it to mean that the meeting must start **and end** within that time frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would definitely understand it as the time slot during which you can choose the time you would like to have the meeting, and translate it to "I can meet with you at any time on Wed between 4 and 9 and/or on Thurs between 4 and 9, so just tell me when do you want to meet and set how long you think the meeting will take"